# Paypal Error #10602 in Magento

Tags: php, magento, paypal

When I first set up Paypal in Magento I had the transaction processing mode set to "authorize". One order was processed with this mode then.

Now I cannot manage to set this first order to "complete". The status stays in "processing". Instead I am getting below error when I want to alter this order or invoice on the product;

```
PayPal gateway has rejected request. Authorization has already been completed (#10602: Authorization completed).
```

The Paypal transaction is authorized and completed. I have changed the transaction processing mode to "sale" now and I am not getting any errors for new orders anymore but I have still the error on the first order and the status is still "processing",

However I want that to be changed to "complete" and finally close the order.
Any ideas how to do it in an easy way?

Answer (score 1):

After change processing mode to "sale", You need to manually update order status in db for force complete the old order. Below Query is useful for set complete order status for specific order's increment id. You need to run this query via phpMyadmin or MySql console for quick solution.

```
UPDATE `sales_flat_order_grid` SET `status` = 'complete' where `increment_id` = YOUR_ORDER_ICREMENT_ID;
UPDATE `sales_flat_order` SET `status` = 'complete', `state` = 'complete'  where `increment_id` = YOUR_ORDER_ICREMENT_ID;
```

If you need change in invoice status detail than you need manually update invoice table
like `sales_flat_invoice_grid` and `sales_flat_invoice`.

Also If you want to revise order history detail so you can update `sales_flat_order_status_history` table.

Comment: Thank you :) That did the first trick. Order is set to complete now. However, the invoice has still the status "processing" but should have the status "complete" too. What needs to be the query in that case?

Comment: For processing order will completed after invoice creation.

Comment: The invoice was created before already. Paypal transaction has the status "autorized" but, however, is completed already as well. So, now I have a complete order but invoice with status "processing". :/

Comment: These processing order is generated before you change processing mode to "sale"?

Comment: yes. the order and invoice were created before I set the paypal configuration to "sale". that is why the paypal transaction did not go through as it was supposed to be and the order and invoice status remained in "processing"

Comment: So you need to run UPDATE query as mentioned in my answer for all old order which created before 'sale' change.

Comment: No. I am afraid that did not work. The status of the invoice is still "pending" (I was wrong before, status of invoice is 'pending'). I guess I have to update the invoice_tables or maybe even the payment_transaction_table ...

Comment: The status of the invoice is "pending" (I was wrong before, status of invoice is 'pending' not processing). I guess it has to do with the paypal transaction that wasn't processed correctly before. I need to let magento know that the invoice is paid so that the status for the invoice goes to 'complete'. Do I have to update the invoice_tables or maybe even the payment_transaction_table for this?

Comment: Invoice pending means your invoice is unpaid, It just authorize and capture is pending or may be some issue with payment transaction process. If you received the payment and Magento shows pending or processing than you need to change your status via my query. Yes invoice table is different than order table.

Comment: Thank you wiram. Yes, I received the payment already but magento shows pending status for the invoice. Which query do I have to use to update the invoice tables so that the invoice shows "paid" as status?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found the second part of the solution myself now :)

I used the following query to update the invoice tables so that the status of the invoice is shown as "paid":

```
UPDATE `sales_flat_invoice_grid` SET `state` = '2' where `increment_id` = YOUR_ORDER_ICREMENT_ID;

UPDATE `sales_flat_invoice` SET `state` = '2', `state` = '2'  where `increment_id` = YOUR_ORDER_ICREMENT_ID;
```

Thanks again, wiram, for your kind help on this issue!
Appreciate it :)